# Выбрать MV* паттерн

Tags: winforms, mvvm, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Решил написать курсовой проект в учебном заведении и попробовать сделать его правильно, какой MV* паттерн посоветуете для небольшого приложения на C# + .NET Framework(WinForms)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model-View-Presenter (MVP).

MVC больше подходит для ASP.NET Core, MVVM требует удобных привязок данных, и подходит больше для WPF. На самом деле [MVVM теперь подходит и для Winforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/whats-new/net70?view=netdesktop-7.0#data-binding-improvements-preview), но только в .NET 7 и новее. Так как вы используете устаревший .NET Framework 4.x, то это не ваш случай.

Comment: В целом согласен, но лично мне больше зашел гибрид - MVPVM. Да нужна некоторая подготовка кодовой базы для более комфортной работы с привязками, которые в формах на самом деле давно есть, просто документация не на виду и примеры кода в документации по формам простые, рабочие, но неудачные.

Comment: @rdorn в .NET 8 на винформах можно будет полноценный MVVM пилить, там привязок нормальных добавят.

Comment: пожуем увидим =) Хотелось бы, все таки пока еще многие нужные контролы приходится руками допиливать до съедобного вида и функциональности. DevExpress не предлагать, слишком тяжелый для моих задач, хотя гриды у них знатные, но с привязками у их контролов них если не хуже, то так же, а еще эти ужасные вечно сползающие слои...

Comment: @rdorn лучше WPF пока объективно для винды ничего нет. Современные GUI еще сыроваты, а винформы морально устарели и сложны, когда нужно красивый GUI сделать.

Comment: о вкусе фломастеров спорить не будем =) Да и WPF тоже уже морально устарел, разве что немного помоложе форм, при этом оба активно используются каждый в своей области и их оттуда вряд ли кто-то новенький сдвинет, пока из винды старые API не выпилят раз и навсегда =)